Is it possible to take the ability to highlight text in a text widget
So I have a text widget that stores buttons within it, and I'm noticing the fact that the user can still highlight items, including the buttons, within the text widget. If you want the code for it, here's a simple example.
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()

box = Text(root, wrap="char", state="disabled", cursor="arrow")
box.pack(fill="both", expand=True)

for i in range(5):
    btn = Button(box, text=f"Button {i+1}")
    box.window_create("end", window=btn, pady=5, padx=5)

root.mainloop()

Now, I have the text widget typing disabled but I can't stop the user from highlighting. I've tried change the highlight color parameter but that didn't do much. While functionally, this isn't a problem, I would rather not have for style. Is this possible?
Update: It's very hard to explain this specific problem so I'll try to explain it with an image.

As you can see because it's a text widget, I have the ability to highlight the items in the widget. I don't want users to have this ability because, it honestly looks ugly.

I don't understand what you're asking.  Are you saying you don't want the selection to be highlighted?  That's contrary to expectations, and is not user-friendly.

@TimRoberts: Usually, you can't highlight text in a button.

On LInux, at least, the button text does not get highlighted.  Just the buttons themselves, as it would with ANY content in a text box.  I just think you're worrying about nothing here.

I updated the post to better explain what I'm trying to solve

Let's be honest - tkinter GUIs are going to tend towards ugly anyways. Highlighting buttons probably isn't going to push it over the edge.

True but I am trying to make it look as best as possible. If this is an impossible task, it's unfortunate but I can accept it.

Did you try setting selectbackground='white'?

Do you want the user to be able to select text but not buttons, or do you want them to not be able to select anything?

Not be able to select anything @BryanOakley

@acw1668 That works, thank you

The OP doesn't want the button being selected while selecting text. My doubt is why to place the buttons inside the text widget? What if there kept outside i.e above the text widget?

@Suramuthu R I want buttons in the text widget for the widget's word wrap function which saves me a lot of time allows me generalize the personalization of repositioning the buttons for different sizes and computers.
